# XML Address GeoCoding Access VBA

Tags: vba, ms-access, geocoding

I am using Access 2010 and am trying to reverse a geocode. I specifify a lat\long location then the result is shown in a listbox. I have a form, with a list box and a command button. The command button has the following onclick event:

```
Dim XMLDoc As New DOMDocument
Dim XMLNode As IXMLDOMNode
Dim i As Long
Dim lat As Double, lng As Double

XMLDoc.Load "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?latlng=37.4250011,-122.0955909&sensor=false"

Do Until XMLDoc.ReadyState = 4
DoEvents
Loop

If Len(XMLDoc.Text) = 0 Then
    Call MsgBox("No data!")
    Exit Sub
End If

Set XMLNode = XMLDoc.selectSingleNode("/GeocodeResponse/result/formatted_address")

For i = 0 To XMLNode.childNodes.length - 1

Me.List1.AddItem Item:=XMLNode.childNodes(i).baseName & XMLNode.childNodes(i).Text

Next i
```

So it retrieves the formatted address.  However, I want to exclude the street number part of the address.  For example, if you go to:

```
http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?latlng=37.4250011,-122.0955909&sensor=false
```

I only want 'Bayshore Parkway, Mountain View, CA 94043, USA'.  How do I build the address components up and then for it to appear as one line in a list box?  Is it possible?

Thanks,

Michael

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of printing the full `.Text` from the node, you can transform it using some simple string functions.

First, declare a string type variable to represent the output:

```
Dim StreetName as String
```

Then, you can assign to your variable:

```
StreetName = XMLNode.childNodes(i).baseName & XMLNode.childNodes(i).Text
```

Then, manipulate it:

```
StreetName = Mid(StreetName, Instr(StreetName, " ")+1)
```

The `Mid` function returns the substring beginning at the position following the first space, which we find using the `Instr` function.  Then add it to your listbox:

```
Me.List1.AddItem StreetName
```

If you need to check for an address number (some may not have one?) then you can do this:

```
StreetName = XMLNode.childNodes(i).baseName & XMLNode.childNodes(i).Text
If IsNumeric(Left(StreetName,1)) Then
    StreetName = Mid(StreetName, Instr(StreetName, " ")+1)
End If

Me.List1.AddItem StreetName
```

Comment: Thanks for this.  However, if an address does not have house number then it chops the first line of the address in half.

Comment: Well you didn't say anything about that in your original question. Do you think you'll be able to use some trial and error and maybe figure out how to handle those exceptions on your own? Why don't you give it a try? Let me know if you run into any problems.

Comment: Ok.  I will give it a shot - I know VBA but not sure about the XML side.

Comment: You don't need XML. Once you have the full address in the `StreetName` variable you can use some logical vba tests to check for numbers. Remember you can evaluate any substring using the string functions like mid, left, instr, etc. also there's the `IsNumeric` function :)

Comment: it may get messy though.  UK postcodes have numbers in them but I need to retain these.  I will give it a shot though.

Comment: If they always start with a numeric then simply test `If IsNumeric(Left(StreetName, 1)) Then ...` that would decide whether an address needs to be parsed further.

Comment: Yes, it is working how I want it to - thank you and much appreciated.  How do I mark your comment as the answer?

Comment: Excellent!  See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) or [here for more detail/screenshot](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) about *how* to mark an answer as accepted. Cheers!!

Comment: I don't think you can mark a comment as the answer though - I can mark your reply as the answer though.

Comment: Right, you would mark my *answer* as the answer :) I revised it to include the detail from that comment, too.

Comment: Great, thanks again.  I can now lookup UK addresses for free using a postcode.  (You usually have to pay for this information)